# string variable values not showing in subprocess.Popen in python

Tags: python

I have a python script whose one of the tasks is to send a mail to an email address. Here is what my code looks like:

```
subject = "Some subject "+str(abc)
content = "Some content"
ml = subprocess.Popen('echo content | mutt -a "file_to_attach.log" -s subject -- myemailid@somedomain.in', shell=True)
ml.communicate()
```

The above code is sending me an email with subject as "subject" and content as "content" instead of the string values that I assigned to them. Can you tell me how to achieve my goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't passing your `content` and `subject` variables into `subprocess.Popen` call, try code below:

```
subject = "Some subject "+str(abc)
content = "Some content"
ml = subprocess.Popen('echo "{content}" | mutt -a "file_to_attach.log" -s "{subject}" -- myemailid@somedomain.in'.format(content=content, subject=subject), shell=True)
ml.communicate()
```

I've used  [str.format method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to pass subject and content into your `subprocess.Popen` call.

Comment: I tried the above, and ran my script using python3 my_script.py. But it is throwing me the error: `Can't stat machine: No such file or directory`. What do I do?

Comment: Although the error is not coming if I do `ml = subprocess.Popen('echo "Random content" | mutt -a "file_to_attach.log" -s "Random subject" -- myemailid@somedomain.in', shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
subject = "Some subject "+str(abc)
content = "Some content"
ml = subprocess.Popen('mutt -a "file_to_attach.log" -s subject -- myemailid@somedomain.in', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
ml.communicate(content)
```

You already have opened a pipe, Mention stdin = subprocess.PIPE and communicate content to subprocess

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
subject = "Some subject "+str(abc)
content = "Some content"
ml = subprocess.Popen(['echo', content, '|', 'mutt', '-a', 'file_to_attach.log', '-s', subject, '-- myemailid@somedomain.in'], shell=True)
ml.communicate()
```